# SQL - Get first level nodes from a nested structure

Tags: mysql, sql, tree

I'm using Joomla and the Docman component. I need to access to some of the stored data in MySQL, but I can't figure how to query them.

What I need is a list of the top nodes of the documents tree, it seems easy (`SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent IS NULL`), but Docman uses another structure.

Here is part of the docman_categories table:

```
docman_category_id INTEGER
title VARCHAR
```

And this table is related to the docman_category_relations, which is the one who define the tree:

```
ancestor_id INT
descendant_id INT
level INT
```

As far as I understant, `ancestor_id` and `descendant_id` are relations to `docman_document_id` from the docman_categories table, and `level` is a number to know how much distance (how much levels) are between `ancestor_id` and `descendant_id`.

And I'm stuck trying to find a query to get the first level items... Can you help me with this query, please?

**More information**

In the docman_category_relations, `ancestor_id` and `descendant_id` haven't any null value.

Comment: what do you get when you do `select * from docman_categories as c left outer join docman_category_relations as r on c.docman_category_id = r.descendant_id where r.descendant_id is null`? as in look for items that are not ever descendants

Comment: @gordatron: I get no rows. As I've just added to the main question, in the docman_category_relations there aren't null values.

Comment: That's a left outer join.. iits saying give me all the docman_categories that don't have matching rows in docman_category_relations (based on descendant_id) .. if the above query returns no rows then it means even top level categories are present in the relations table as descendants. now try this with a docman_category_id you KNOW is at the top level and see what you get `select * from docman_categories as c left outer join docman_category_relations as r on c.docman_category_id = r.descendant_id where c.docman_category_id = 5` (assuming docman_categery_id 5 is a top level menu item)

Comment: @gordatron: It works: it returns the full docman_categories row, and the docman_category_rows, with values ancestor_id = 5, descendant_id = 5 and level = 0. But ALL the nodes has this values (descendant_id = id, ancestor_id = id, level = 0), even when they aren't top nodes...

Comment: Dang! if you could run the last query for something you know if a top level node and something you know is not a top level node and post the result then we can look for clues together.

Comment: I'll post the final query in a moment. A coworker has helped me creating the correct query.

Comment: good News!, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct query to get only the top nodes:

```
SELECT * 
FROM docman_category_relations dcr 
WHERE
    (SELECT COUNT(ancestor_id) 
     FROM docman_category_relations r 
     WHERE r.descendant_id = cr.descendant_id) = 1
```